# PHP is not able to read data sent in jQuery.ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, stringify

JavaScript code:

```
var data = {"hiSO": "my very complex - nested objects/arrays - data object"};

var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "postTestingResult.php",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: {"data": JSON.stringify(data)},
  dataType: "json",
  success: ajaxSuccess,
  error: ajaxError
});
```

PHP Code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(!empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

    //do things with data

    echo json_encode(array("success" => "thanks for the info!"));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "'data' is not set or is NULL"));
}
```

No matter how I structure the data, $_POST['data'] always seems to be empty (specifically, Undefined). If you want a full copy of the data object I am using, check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RNqR/1/). Appreciate the help, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've told the server you're sending JSON (via `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`), but you're not sending JSON, you're sending URI-encoded data. This is because you've given jQuery an object for the `data` option (an object with one property, whose value is a JSON string).

Your PHP code expects URI-encoded data, so to fix it just remove the `contentType` option so jQuery uses its default.

If you really want to send JSON instead (which would require changing your PHP), change

```
data: {"data": JSON.stringify(data)},
```

to

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

or

```
data: JSON.stringify({data: data}),
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I would have ever though of that! And I edited my question to include the var j = jQuery.noConflict(); so as to remove confusion for others.

Comment: As a follow-up question, is there any reason why I should not send as JSON? Can i just sent it plain? I've always been under the assumption it had to be in some format, JSON and XML being the two most popular

Comment: @MatthewHerbst: You have to send data in *some* format. The most popular format for *sending* to the server is URI-encoded (technically, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`), which is what you're using in your outer layer (your POST contains a single URI-encoded field, `data`; the value of that field is a JSON string). The popular formats for sending data *from* the server to the client are JSON and XML. For sending complex data to the server, JSON-over-URI-encoding (what you've done) seems just fine, and I've used it in the past.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why `would require changing your PHP` if he send his `data` as `JSON`? I think his PHP code is OK for that case?

Comment: @Felix I'm a bit confused on what to do for the PHP side of it too. I like the `data: JSON.stringify({data: data}),` way of doing it because that puts all my data within the $_POST['data'] field. However, does PHP automatically decode the JSON? If not, how does PHP know to put data into `$_POST['data']` if it just gets posted a big JSON string? I guess this comes down to asking where exactly I do the `json_decode()`

Comment: @Felix: He's using `$_POST` to access a POST variable called `data` and then calling `json_decode` on that variable's value. That works if he sends URI-encoded data because PHP decodes the URI-encoded data, and sees that it says to create a variable called `"data"` with a big string value. PHP doesn't know what the string contains; the OP's code does, though, and uses `json_decode`. If he sends the POST data using `Content-Type` `application/json`, then either PHP has to interpret the JSON (which I don't think it does), or he has to *not* use `json_decode` (because PHP interpreted the data).

Comment: @MatthewHerbst: If you're sending the data using `data: {data: JSON.stringify(...)}` and *not* using `contentType: "application/json..."`, then your PHP code is using `json_decode` in the right place.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much - I really appreciate it!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've run into a problem. For some reason, arrays are being interpreted as strings once json_decoded in PHP. For example, {"apps": [1,2,3]} gets encoded to JSON as "{"apps":"[1,2,3]"}" and then in PHP this for some reason becomes array('apps' => '[{"app_id": 0, ...}]') which obviously screws up trying to access any elements in 'apps' since it is now a string rather than an array. Any idea what's going on? [Check out this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WwGnSctn) for the full JSON and PHP data objects. Thank you

Comment: I've [posted a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851766/why-is-json-decodedata-true-converting-an-array-to-a-string) for this