# Getting empty array in PHP while using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have this jQuery $.ajax script:

```
var data = JSON.stringify( selected_products );

$.ajax({ type: "POST", 
    url: "addtocart.php", 
    data: data, 
    dataType: 'application/json'
});
```

And I am posting this to a really simple PHP script:

```
$selected_products = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
print_r($selected_products);
```

This is an example of what I'm sending; this is outgoing data in Chrome DevTools:

```
data:[{"id":"RECOLOURBALM","option":"Black","quantity":1},{"id":"TOWELS","quantity":1}]
```

However this is the console readout for the response:

```
Array
(
)
```

I think the request is succeeding and data is being passed, but the responses are all empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This could possibly help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851766/why-is-json-decodedata-true-converting-an-array-to-a-string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: This question comes up a lot and has been answered many times before. Check one of the links above

Comment: @darragh enright the issue was with the stringify..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$selected_products = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
echo $selected_products[0]['id'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_POST;
echo '<br>';
var_dump($_POST);
```

add data to your post

You are now getting null that's because of the stringify given there. Please change the code like this.It will surely work.

```
var data=[{"id":"RECOLOURBALM","option":"Bordeaux","quantity":1},{"id":"TOWELS","quantity‌​":1}];
//data = JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "addtocart.php", 
    data: {'data':data}, 
    success:function(returndata){
        console.log(returndata);
    }
});
```

Remove the stringify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My response is now: <br><br>NULL

Comment: print $selected_products
remove all the other lines..what's the out put

Comment: also add  a datatype as json in the ajax

Comment: For print($selected_products); I get no response?

Comment: add contentType: 'application/json' to the ajax.. did you get anything when printing $_post variable

Comment: print ($_POST) gave me nothing. Also how do I change the data type for the shorthand $.post? have updated op

Comment: user this instead of $.post
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});

Comment: Okay, I have updated the OP with the code you provided, but I'm still not getting anything?

Comment: can you try this 
$selected_product=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159224/discussion-between-darshan-and-aaranihlus).

Answer (score 1):

If the `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`, you have to receive data as follows.

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

`$_POST` will receive the data from request, which has `Content-Type`: `x-www-form-urlencoded`(Form Data)